List to set transformation seems to change order of elements
I am creating a certificate and I can specify the transit countries in it, they must be saved in the order in which they were set by the user. But under some circumstances, countries may be saved in random order
I looked at the logs and it turned out that the order changes somewhere while converting from a dto to an entity. All mapping takes place using the mapstruct library and I suspect that the countryDTOListToCountrySet method is to blame. But I can't find any information on whether the order may be confused when converting from list to set. Can this happen? And if not, how can I log the mapper class generated by mapstruct? So that I can see what happens with each step in mapping DTO to entity
Im my case there is field in entity
private Set<Country> transitCountries = new HashSet<>();

Field in dto
private List<CountryDTO> transitCountries;

Both classes use @Data from lombok if its matters
And this is what mapstruct generates
protected Set<Country> countryDTOListToCountrySet(List<CountryDTO> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<Country> set = new HashSet<Country>( Math.max( (int) ( list.size() / .75f ) + 1, 16 ) );
        for ( CountryDTO countryDTO : list ) {
            set.add( countryDTOToCountry( countryDTO ) );
        }

        return set;
    }

I tried changing HashSet to LinkedHashSet but it doesnt seem to change anything. Idk if it doesnt work because of lombok or something else...

A [MCVE] would improve your Question.

@BasilBourque I added some code thank you for recommendation

tl;dr
A Set has no defined encounter order. Instead use a SequencedSet implementation such as LinkedHashSet.
SequencedSet< Person > personsSequencedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>( personsList ) ;  

The MapStruct  1.5+ documentation says that it by default does use LinkedHashSet as the implementation when you specify a Set. If you are not seeing insertion-order preserved, check to see (a) if your code base overrides that default, or (b) if you are using an earlier version of MapStruct before 1.5.
Details
Set is unordered
A Set by definition has no defined encounter order.
You said:

I suspect that the countryDTOListToCountrySet method is to blam

When making a Set from a List, the order is lost.
You said:

whether the order may be confused when converting from list to set.

The elements of a resulting Set may be in any order. That order may even change each time you iterate.
SequencedCollection
If you care about the encounter order, then use a collection which implements the SequencedCollection interface. See JEP 431: Sequenced Collections. See also video of presentation, Sequenced Collections By Stuart Marks.
The List interface is a sub-interface of SequencedCollection. So ArrayList is one such implementation, implementing both List and SequencedCollection.
SequencedSet
If you want the features of a Set, but need to rely on an encounter order, use an implementation of the interface SequencedSet, a sub-interface of SequencedCollection. Java comes bundled with three implementations:

ConcurrentSkipListSet
TreeSet
LinkedHashSet

The first two use either the natural order of the elements, or uses a Comparator implementation provided by you. These two classes also implement the NavigableSet & SortedSet interfaces.
The third implementation, LinkedHashSet, maintains insertion-order.
LinkedHashSet
So, if you want a collection that has some properties of a Set (such as eliminating duplicates) but also retains an encounter order based on insertion, use LinkedHashSet.
SequencedSet< Person > personsSequencedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>( personsList ) ;  

See chart taken from JEP 431.


Great point about "The MapStruct documentation says that it by default does use LinkedHashSet as the implementation when you specify a Set". Just to clarify it a bit. MapStruc tis using LinkedHashSet from 1.5.0.Final, this means that if you are using an earlier version HashSet will be used.

@Filip Well, that’s important! I added that fact to the Answer. Thank you.
